# Extending LINQ Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, expression

Newbie LINQ Expressions question-

```
Expression<Func<TLookupModel, TValue>> idSelector;
IEnumerable<TLookupModel> source;
TValue id;
```

I'm trying to do (pseudo-code):

```
source.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(x => idSelector == id)
```

My feeble attempt thus far is along the lines of:

```
var expressionParam = idSelector.Parameters.First();

ConstantExpression selectedValueConstant = Expression.Constant(id, typeof(TValue));

var idEqualExpression = Expression.Equal(idSelector, selectedValueConstant);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TLookupModel, bool>>(idEqualExpression, expressionParam);

var selectedSourceItem = source.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(lambda);
```

I think that gives you a guess as to how I've been thinking so far. I've tried with and without the parameters, different combinations of Expression method calls, trying to get the "parameter" to come from the `FirstOrDefault()` call, but after reading lots of tutorials I can't get my head around how to extend a "member" expression to equal a constant in this way.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` takes a lambda, not a boolean expression. Can you correct the sample?

Comment: @NetMage I did mark it as pseudo-code, but edited all the same.

Comment: So it seems like `idselector` is a `Func<>` but you aren't passing in a parameter... these details matter if you are trying to work with `Expression` and build them. Did you mean `idselector(x) == id`? Can you show a sample of `idselector`? I think you need a Replace `ExpressionVisitor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got really close.

Your idExpression is an Expression in the form of `x => x.Property`. However, you're passing the whole expression to the Equal expression. Change that to pass only the body:

```
var idEqualExpression = Expression.Equal(idSelector.Body, selectedValueConstant);
```

Then you can compile the lambda and pass it to FirstOrDefault without casting to a queryable:

```
var selectedSourceItem = source.FirstOrDefault(lambda.Compile());
```